# Sending email from netsuite using freemarker template engine

Tags: netsuite

Can someone help me to work my task on netsuite Sending email. The email body should be generated with the freemarker template engine using nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer. I try to used the sample on the help page in netsuite but it doesnt work. Can somebody explain or give me a example on this API.

By the way i can sent email using suitelet, my problem is the email body.
Thank you.

Comment: what record are you trying to use the template for?

Comment: @vVinceth location record

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have your scriptable template. This should run OK.

```
var emailTempId = 1; // internal id of the email template
var emailTemp = nlapiLoadRecord('emailtemplate',emailTempId); 
var emailSubj = emailTemp.getFieldValue('subject');
var emailBody = emailTemp.getFieldValue('content');
var records = new Object();
records['transaction'] = '1'; //internal id of Transaction
var salesOrder = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', 1);
var renderer = nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer();
renderer.addRecord('transaction', salesOrder );
renderer.setTemplate(emailSubj);
renderSubj = renderer.renderToString();
renderer.setTemplate(emailBody);
renderBody = renderer.renderToString();
nlapiSendEmail(-5, 'email@domain.com', renderSubj, renderBody , null, null, records);
```

Comment: i try to used the sample you gave, i got this error Email Template (CRMSDK - Deprecated) with id 1 does not exist. Check template id and template's type

Comment: that means your template is not scriptable template. Non-CRMSDK Template cannot be used if you will be utilizing nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer because you need to load the template and when you load the template using the nlapiLoadRecord that means you are editing it. Since the CRMSDK was deprecated you cannot edit it hence you got the error.

You might want to convert your template to the new Scriptable Template

Answer (score 0):

The new Scriptable Template that is using the FreeMarker only supports Entity, Transaction, Custom Record, Case, & Project Record. Other records might work but based on Answer Id: 32621 from the SuiteAnswers those record are the ones that will be supported.

Comment: Can you give me sample how to work on transaction. i used the same code use on help pagem but it doesnt work. Thank you